# Eight queens problem, wondering about the non-unique solutions

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I've done the code that generates all the solutions. But know I am suppose to filter out any redundant solutions based on symmetry and rotations. I have code for vertical symmetry, horizontal symmetry, rotation $90$, $180$ and $270$. The bit that remains is removing symmetry about the the diagonals. / and \ of the board. I guess I can rotate it $90^\circ$ instead of making code for both diagonals. I want to implement the diagonal "\". I drew up some points.
From bottom part to the upper part.
$(1, 3)$-> $(6, 8)

$(2, 1)$ -> $(8, 7)$

From top part to bottom part.
$(4, 6)$->$(3, 5)$
$(5, 6)$->$(3, 4)$

I'm not sure what formulas would do this for me. And what about chess pieces on the diagonal it self, they would just stay put I guess?

Comment: My code gives 23 "unique" answers without filtering for the diagonal ones.

Comment: I need it to work with a n*n board.

Comment: It would be better if this question describes the "eight queens problem" in more detail, or at least contains a link to a description of the problem elsewhere. At least one reason for this is that readers of this question want to know what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a,b)\to(9-b,9-a){}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Now I just feel stupid haha. How would it be if the diagonal went the other way? "/"?

Comment: @Algific: for the diagonal "/" it is (a, b) -> (b, a).